# Is there a difference between IsNull(x) and x = ""?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In if statements I always have to use `if isnull(x) or x = "" then`

What is the difference between the two and why doesn't each of them work in some cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NULL` is the absence of a value*

`""` is a zero-length string

Due to implicit conversion - an object that hasn't been populated yet *might* return true for both cases. However if you were to place a value of `""` in there, it would return False for `isnull()` and True for `= ""`

*<sup>*Credit to [Comintern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4088852/comintern) for improving the explanation (see comments)</sup>*

Comment: It might be more accurate to say null is the absence of value to avoid confusing it with `Nothing`. `IsNull(Nothing)` evaluates to false because `Nothing` is an object reference.

Comment: And you forgot _Empty_.

Comment: I would say it's more like an empty nullable variable, than nothing, as this would confuse matters `Dim o As Object: Set o = New Excel.Application: Set o = Nothing: Debug.Print IsNull(o)`  this returns false

Comment: @Gustav - `Empty` is technically a `Variant` of type `VT_EMPTY` - `IsNull(Empty)` also evaluates to false.

Comment: @Gustav I've not forgotten it - there is no mention of `IsEmpty()` in the OP's code

Comment: True, but if x can be _Null_ it must be declared as a _Variant_ and, if not having been assigned a value, `IsNull(x)` will return False while `x = ""` returns True. Thus, you have to use both checks - or use `Nz(x) = ""` which behaves as expected in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

If you do that check, to makes sense x must be a *Variant*, and Null is not "Nothing". Nothing means Empty and a special check for that exists.

Run this and see:

```
Dim x   As Variant

Debug.Print IsEmpty(x)  ' True
Debug.Print IsNull(x)   ' False
Debug.Print x = ""      ' True
Debug.Print Nz(x) = ""  ' True

x = Null
Debug.Print IsEmpty(x)  ' False
Debug.Print IsNull(x)   ' True
Debug.Print x = ""      ' Null
Debug.Print Nz(x) = ""  ' True

x = ""
Debug.Print IsEmpty(x)  ' False
Debug.Print IsNull(x)   ' False
Debug.Print x = ""      ' True
Debug.Print Nz(x) = ""  ' True
```

Comment: you could add results as a comments right to `debug.print` lines to improve readability...

Answer (score 2):

As said by the other answers, null is nothing, "" is an empty string.

To test for both null and empty variables in access VBA, use the following:

```
If nz([variable], "") = "" Then do stuff
```

The nz function converts null variables to "" or 0

Answer (score 0):

when I want to check for a null/ empty string
I use

```
If x & "" <> "" then
```

Answer (score -1):

`isnull` means the value is not known while **edit:** `""` means it is zero-length string*

---

<sub>*Credit: @Macro Man.</sub>

Comment: _Empty_ is very different from "".

Comment: Correct. my mistake. (Although i see this is a common misconception since i noticed now that @Erik von Asmuth answered this as well " "" is an empty string."

(Although i do like his idea of using `If nz([variable], "") = "" Then`)
[i am pretty new here - am i supposed to edit what i wrote?]

Comment: Yes, the Nz method seems unbeatable. If you can edit your answer, by all means just go ahead. Merry Christmas.